# Spring security set up access control with oauth2 token

Tags: spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security, jwt

I am discovering oauth2. I have managed to create a sample which return JWToken and REST protected by this token. 
Now i would like to improve this by adding access-control in my protected REST interface.
Why ? Because i would like users like ADMIN, READER access some URL or not.

Following http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html
it is possible over expression-handler in http node.
Here is the configuration i have added to my xml config :

```
<sec:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<sec:http pattern="/protected/**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/protected/**" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter"
        before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    <sec:expression-handler ref="myexpressionHandler" />
</sec:http>

<bean id="myexpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler"> 
</bean>
```

log :
févr. 04, 2015 4:09:31 PM org.springframework.security.config.method.GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser parse
INFOS: Expressions were enabled for method security but no SecurityExpressionHandler was configured. All hasPermision() expressions will evaluate to false.
févr. 04, 2015 4:09:31 PM org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser checkFilterChainOrder

But with my JWTtoken I successfully get the protected resource.

My controller:

```
@Component
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/protected")
public class HelloWorldRest {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(HelloWorldRest.class);

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting/{name}")
    public Greeting greeting(@PathVariable String name) {
        LOG.info("Fonction greeting : " + name);
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template,
                name + ", I am Mister Toto"));
    }

}
```

I have tested with an user who get authoritiesGrant={ ROLE_NONE }

Thanks,
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error message "SecurityExpressionHandler was configured" you should add the expression handler to your global-method-security. Like this:

```
<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
  <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security> 
<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
```

Instead of defining your own bean for the WebSecurityExpressionHandler (as you dod in the question) you can additionally use:

```
<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```